# How can i force the DbUpdateConcurrencyException to be raised even if i am passing the FormCollection to my Post action method instead of an object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, optimistic-concurrency

i have the following action method inside my asp.net mvc web application , which will raise a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` as intended to handle any concurrent conflicts that might happen:-

```
[HttpPost] 
        public ActionResult Edit(Assessment a) 
        {            try 
            { 
                if (ModelState.IsValid)  
                { 
                    elearningrepository.UpdateAssessment(a); 
                    elearningrepository.Save(); 
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = a.AssessmentID }); 
                } 
            } 
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex) 
            { 
                var entry = ex.Entries.Single(); 
                var clientValues = (Assessment)entry.Entity; 

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The record you attempted to edit was"  
                 + "modified by another user after you got the original value."); 
                               } 
            catch (DataException) 
            { 
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists contact your system administrator."); 
            }        
            return View(a);}
```

but to avoid any over binding attacks i have define a `[Bind(Include = "Date, Title")]`  on the object class, but this raised a problem to me as the above action method will return an exception even if no concurrent conflict occur becuase the model binder will not be able to bind the object ID and other values ,, so i have changed my action method to the following:-

```
[HttpPost] 
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection) 
        { 
            Assessment a = elearningrepository.GetAssessment(id); 

            try 
            { 
                if (TryUpdateModel(a)) 
                { 
                    elearningrepository.UpdateAssessment(a); 
                    elearningrepository.Save(); 
                    return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = a.AssessmentID }); 
                } 
            } 
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex) 
            { 
                var entry = ex.Entries.Single(); 
                var clientValues = (Assessment)entry.Entity; 

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The record you attempted to edit was"  
                 + "modified by another user after you got the original value."); 
            } 
            catch (DataException) 
            {                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists contact your system administrator."); 
            }return View(a);
```

but writting the action method as in the second approach will not raise the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` under any situation (even if a concurrency conflict occurs!!!).

**so me question is how i can make sure that the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` will be raised if any conflict occur and at the same time to make sure that no over binding attack might occur by defining `[Bind(Include = "Date, Title")]`?
thanks in advance for any help and suggestions .**
BR

Answer (score 2):

Stop using forms collection and use a view model, thats a far better approach.

Also I have an action filter I wrote to handle the concurrency exceptions (MVC4 handles entity exceptions now finally has pat of validation just not the concurrency exceptions). Its a work in progress but should work ok as is, that much has been tested : )

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Gecko.Framework.Mvc.ActionFilters
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Author: Adam Tuliper
    /// adam.tuliper@gmail.com
    /// completedevelopment.blogspot.com
    /// www.secure-coding.com
    /// Use freely, just please retain original credit.
    /// 
    /// This attribute attempts to intercept DbUpdateConcurrencyException to write out original/new values
    /// to the screen for the user to review.
    /// It assumes the following:
    /// 1. There is a [Timestamp] attribute on an entity framework model property
    /// 2. The only differences that we care about from the posted data to the record currently in the database are 
    /// only yhe model state field. We do not have access to a model at this point, as an exception was raised so there was no
    /// return View(model) that we have a model to process from.
    /// As such, we have to look at the fields in the modelstate and try to find matching fields on the entity and then display the differences.
    /// This may not work in all cases. 
    /// This class will look at your model to get the property names. It will then check your
    /// Entities current values vs. db values for these property names.
    /// The behavior can be changed.
    /// </summary>
    public class HandleConcurrencyException : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter //ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private PropertyMatchingMode _propertyMatchingMode;
        /// <summary>
        /// This defines when the concurrencyexception happens, 
        /// </summary>
        public enum PropertyMatchingMode
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Uses only the field names in the model to check against the entity. This option is best when you are using 
            /// View Models with limited fields as opposed to an entity that has many fields. The ViewModel (or model) field names will
            /// be used to check current posted values vs. db values on the entity itself.
            /// </summary>
            UseViewModelNamesToCheckEntity = 0,
            /// <summary>
            /// Use any non-matching value fields on the entity (except timestamp fields) to add errors to the ModelState.
            /// </summary>
            UseEntityFieldsOnly = 1,
            /// <summary>
            /// Tells the filter to not attempt to add field differences to the model state.
            /// This means the end user will not see the specifics of which fields caused issues
            /// </summary>
            DontDisplayFieldClashes = 2
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The main method, called by the mvc runtime when an exception has occured.
        /// This must be added as a global filter, or as an attribute on a class or action method.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled && filterContext.Exception is DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                //Get original and current entity values
                DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex = (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)filterContext.Exception;
                var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
                //problems with ef4.1/4.2 here because of context/model in different projects.
                //var databaseValues = entry.CurrentValues.Clone().ToObject();
                //var clientValues = entry.Entity;
                //So - if using EF 4.1/4.2 you may use this workaround
                var clientValues = entry.CurrentValues.Clone().ToObject();
                entry.Reload();
                var databaseValues = entry.CurrentValues.ToObject();

                List<string> propertyNames;

                filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The record you attempted to edit "
                        + "was modified by another user after you got the original value. The "
                        + "edit operation was canceled and the current values in the database "
                        + "have been displayed. If you still want to edit this record, click "
                        + "the Save button again to cause your changes to be the current saved values.");
                PropertyInfo[] entityFromDbProperties = databaseValues.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                if (_propertyMatchingMode == PropertyMatchingMode.UseViewModelNamesToCheckEntity)
                {
                    //We dont have access to the model here on an exception. Get the field names from modelstate:
                    propertyNames = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Keys.ToList();
                }
                else if (_propertyMatchingMode == PropertyMatchingMode.UseEntityFieldsOnly)
                {
                    propertyNames = databaseValues.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public).Select(o => o.Name).ToList();
                }
                else
                {
                    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                    UpdateTimestampField(filterContext, entityFromDbProperties, databaseValues);
                    filterContext.Result = new ViewResult() { ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData };
                    return;
                }



                UpdateTimestampField(filterContext, entityFromDbProperties, databaseValues);

                //Get all public properties of the entity that have names matching those in our modelstate.
                foreach (var propertyInfo in entityFromDbProperties)
                {

                    //If this value is not in the ModelState values, don't compare it as we don't want
                    //to attempt to emit model errors for fields that don't exist.

                    //Compare db value to the current value from the entity we posted.

                    if (propertyNames.Contains(propertyInfo.Name))
                    {
                        if (propertyInfo.GetValue(databaseValues, null) != propertyInfo.GetValue(clientValues, null))
                        {
                            var currentValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(databaseValues, null);
                            if (currentValue == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue.ToString()))
                            {
                                currentValue = "Empty";
                            }

                            filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError(propertyInfo.Name, "Current value: "
                                 + currentValue);
                        }
                    }

                    //TODO: hmm.... how can we only check values applicable to the model/modelstate rather than the entity we saved?
                    //The problem here is we may only have a few fields used in the viewmodel, but many in the entity
                    //so we could have a problem here with that.
                }

                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult() { ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData };
            }
        }

        public HandleConcurrencyException()
        {
            _propertyMatchingMode = PropertyMatchingMode.UseViewModelNamesToCheckEntity;
        }

        public HandleConcurrencyException(PropertyMatchingMode propertyMatchingMode)
        {
            _propertyMatchingMode = propertyMatchingMode;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Searches the database loaded entity values for a field that has a [Timestamp] attribute.
        /// It then writes a string version of ther byte[] timestamp out to modelstate, assuming 
        /// we have a timestamp field on the page that caused the concurrency exception.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
        /// <param name="entityFromDbProperties"></param>
        /// <param name="databaseValues"></param>
        private void UpdateTimestampField(ExceptionContext filterContext, PropertyInfo[] entityFromDbProperties, object databaseValues)
        {
            foreach (var propertyInfo in entityFromDbProperties)
            {
                var attributes = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributesData();

                //If this is a timestamp field, we need to set the current value.
                foreach (CustomAttributeData attr in attributes)
                {
                    if (typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.TimestampAttribute).IsAssignableFrom(attr.Constructor.DeclaringType))
                    {
                        //This currently works only with byte[] timestamps. You can use dates as timestampts, but support is not provided here.
                        byte[] timestampValue = (byte[])propertyInfo.GetValue(databaseValues, null);
                        //we've found the timestamp. Add it to the model.
                        filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Add(propertyInfo.Name, new ModelState());
                        filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.SetModelValue(propertyInfo.Name,
                            new ValueProviderResult(Convert.ToBase64String(timestampValue), Convert.ToBase64String(timestampValue), null));
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, your approach seesm totally new to me but i will try it . but do u mean that the approach i am using will not always catch the concurrency exceptions? BR

Comment: and i do not want to use MVC 4 right now ad it is still a beta version and as mentioned in its decumentation it is not supposed to be used in live system ...

Comment: i tried your approach but i got the following error "Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments" on   "List propertyNames;" inside the above class. any suggestion about this error ? BR

Comment: my comment on mvc4 was just an FYI and was not targeted specifically to your issue (as I mentioned validation exceptions, not concurrency exceptions). The problem with your approach is you have to duplicate it in every single controller - why would you want to do that when you can globally apply to all action methods (or select those without duplicating code). As for the code not working, copy it out again - there were <> in there which the post interprets as html. I've encoded and reposted.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know why I had to change

```
if (propertyInfo.GetValue(databaseValues, null) != propertyInfo.GetValue(clientValues, null))
```

to

```
if (!Equals(propertyInfo.GetValue(databaseValues,null), propertyInfo.GetValue(clientValues,null)))
```

It was giving me false positives for anything that was not a string.

After I made that change it worked for me.

Here is the complete modified function

```
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled && filterContext.Exception is DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            //Get original and current entity values
            DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex = (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)filterContext.Exception;
            var entry = ex.Entries.Single();

            //problems with ef4.1/4.2 here because of context/model in different projects.
            //var databaseValues = entry.CurrentValues.Clone().ToObject();
            //var clientValues = entry.Entity;
            //So - if using EF 4.1/4.2 you may use this workaround                
            var clientValues = entry.CurrentValues.Clone().ToObject();
            entry.Reload();
            var databaseValues = entry.CurrentValues.ToObject();



            List<string> propertyNames;

            filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The record you attempted to edit "
                    + "was modified by another user after you got the original value. The "
                    + "edit operation was canceled and the current values in the database "
                    + "have been displayed. If you still want to edit this record, click "
                    + "the Save button again to cause your changes to be the current saved values.");
            PropertyInfo[] entityFromDbProperties = databaseValues.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            if (_propertyMatchingMode == PropertyMatchingMode.UseViewModelNamesToCheckEntity)
            {
                //We dont have access to the model here on an exception. Get the field names from modelstate:
                propertyNames = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Keys.ToList();
            }
            else if (_propertyMatchingMode == PropertyMatchingMode.UseEntityFieldsOnly)
            {
                propertyNames = databaseValues.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public).Select(o => o.Name).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                UpdateTimestampField(filterContext, entityFromDbProperties, databaseValues);
                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult() { ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData };
                return;
            }



            UpdateTimestampField(filterContext, entityFromDbProperties, databaseValues);

            //Get all public properties of the entity that have names matching those in our modelstate.
            foreach (var propertyInfo in entityFromDbProperties)
            {

                //If this value is not in the ModelState values, don't compare it as we don't want
                //to attempt to emit model errors for fields that don't exist.

                //Compare db value to the current value from the entity we posted.

                if (propertyNames.Contains(propertyInfo.Name))
                {
                    //if (propertyInfo.GetValue(databaseValues, null) != propertyInfo.GetValue(clientValues, null))
                    if (!Equals(propertyInfo.GetValue(databaseValues,null), propertyInfo.GetValue(clientValues,null)))
                    {
                        var currentValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(databaseValues, null);
                        if (currentValue == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentValue.ToString()))
                        {
                            currentValue = "Empty";
                        }

                        filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError(propertyInfo.Name, "Database value: "
                             + currentValue);
                    }
                }

                //TODO: hmm.... how can we only check values applicable to the model/modelstate rather than the entity we saved?
                //The problem here is we may only have a few fields used in the viewmodel, but many in the entity
                //so we could have a problem here with that.
            }

            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;                
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult() { ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData };
        }
    }
```