# How do I load associated entities from an ExceptionContext in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an exception filter, which checks for concurrency issues (`DbUpdateConcurrencyException`).

I want to show the user the current value stored on the database that they will be overriding if they continue with their save.

When I work through the `ExceptionContext` parameter to my `OnException` method I only have a detached entity, `exception.Entries.Single()` and so for foreign key columns the best message I can show is

```
The current value for PersonId is 23123.
```

How can I get at the related entity and show

```
'The current value for Person is John Smith'.
```

That is, show the property of `Person.Name`.

Comment: Is the option to overwrite data a feature? It's generally inadvisable to rely on exceptions for handling expected behaviour.

Comment: I got the code from here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731425/how-can-i-force-the-dbupdateconcurrencyexception-to-be-raised-even-if-i-am-passi/9742622#9742622 It works pretty well, I just want to make the messages more user friendly

Comment: The post you've linked to uses exceptions correctly, i.e. for (as the name suggests) exceptional circumstances. When the program fails. It sounds like you're using them as part of normal program flow, which is just plain bad (and computationally expensive). Swap your exception handler out for some conditional logic and save exceptions for when something goes wrong.

Comment: That's just the way I described it :) My code is exactly the same as the one I linked to